# Pycharm imported Opencv-python lib can not use cv2 module directly

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I have installed the opencv-python lib ([Here the installed lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OMoR.png)) but when I use a function (`cv2.VideoCapture(0)`) of the imported cv2 (`import cv2`) module, pycharm raised the error:

`AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'VideoCapture'`

While in the python basic IDE (IDLE) it works great.
I saw the solution for pycharm was to import cv2 this way:

`from cv2 import cv2`

But I don't understand why I should import it like that in pycharm